# Taylor coefficients of certain "deformed" Bessel functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions, bessel-functions, spherical-coordinates

**Related links / discussions.**

- (1) [How to compute $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi (\cos y + x)^{2k}dy$ and similar integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4244333/168758)
- (2) Answer to (1) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4244473/168758

Let $I_0$ and $I_1$ be the Bessel functions of the first and second kind respectively, and for fixed $x \in \mathbb R$, define functions $(a,b) \mapsto F_0(a,b;x)$ and $(a,b) \mapsto F_1(a,b;x)$ by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{split}
F_0(a,b;x) &:= e^{(a+b)x}I_0(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}),\\
F_1(a,b;x) &:= e^{(a+b)x}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}I_1(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}).
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray*}

> **Question.** In the Taylor expansion of $F_0$ and $F_1$ respectively, what is the coeficient of $a^k b^l$ ?